# Substring in Key parameter

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I am working on my CouchDB project, where I want to create a specific view for my database.
It has proven that one of my key parameters has an ID as part of its name, but the other part is unique. ex "unique_ID_unique":"Value".
So brute force solutions like changing the name and/or how it is saved is not preferred.

To make it clear the ID is different for every entry (date).
I tried to modify it by using regex rules but it returns **NULL** for the key part.

```
emit(doc[/_unique$/], doc['something.else']);
```

Does someone have any idea why it is like that?

P.S: I already had a question like this yesterday, but due to the insufficient information that I gave, it led to wrong answers and I had to delete it.

Comment: Are the `_` part of the key?

Comment: yes they are, do you think that is the reason why it is not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a function that extract the unique key from a particular one:

```
var key = "blabla_120391029301923_blabla";
var keySplitted = key.split("_"); //Value: ["blabla","120391029301923","blabla"]
var uniqueKey = keySplitted[2]; //Value: blabla
```

From this, you can create a view what will map each documents and index them with your key.

```
function(doc){
  var keySplitted = doc._id.split("_");
  if(keySplitted.length == 3){
    emit(keySplitted[2]);
  }
}
```

The previous map ids from this:

- evening_01012018_food
- morning_02012018_musc
- evening_01022018_food

To this:

- food
- musc
- food

## UPDATE

From offline discussion, I was able to understand that the objects to index had this content:

```
{
  "_id": "doc_1",
  "_rev": "1-89d017d9e5c82ee56d9beec2756fec99",
  "type": "googrtt",
  "ssrc_3685071425_send.bytesSent": "33621"
}
```

So with this document, the properties had to be split.

The final view content looks like this:

```
function (doc) {
  for(key in doc){
    var splitKey= key.split('_');
    if(splitKey.length === 3){
      emit(splitKey[2],doc[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your replay. That could work if I can set what var key is... that is the problem, I don't know it at the beginning. I just know there will be sth ending with "_blabla" but I dont know the middle part

Comment: So you want to find documents that have a key ending with a certain suffix?

Comment: Yes, the suffix is always unique. Example
"morning_01012018_musc":"0000", "evening_01012018_food":"1111", "morning_02012018_musc":"2222", "evening_01022018_food":"3333"

so I cant put the whole key part since the date changes (01.01.2018 then 02.01.2018) but I want the _food from both of the days. A brute force solution is yes possible, to change the way the name of the key is given, but I am looking right now for a creative solution (if there is any) that would give me the desired results, just by telling him how my key is ending/ what is the suffix

Comment: Create a map function. In your map function, use my code example and emit(keySplitted[2], value). This will index the last part of your key which is unique. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but CouchDB is not allowing me to use .split

Comment: What version of CouchDB are you using? I tested witch CouchDB 2.1.2 and it's working fine.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. But I thought the topic was closed. Yet I am eager now to solve it like you say it is possible. I have just installed the newest CouchDB v2.2.0. Put I still get a red .split when I try to define my function. Do you define it in your view ?